# Render two header buttons on react navigation top bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to show two buttons on the header of a react navigation top bar.

The render works, if I do it like this:

```
static navigationOptions = {
   title: "Categories",        
   headerRight: [<HeaderBarButton image={<HeaderBarButtonSearchImage/>} />, <HeaderBarButton image={<HeaderBarButtonInfoImage/>} />],        
};
```

But then, react shows me this warning, because I'm passing an array without keys.

[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvIiC.jpg)

And then, I try like this but I got an error

```
headerRight: [ 
  {key: '1', item: <HeaderBarButton image={<HeaderBarButtonSearchImage></HeaderBarButtonSearchImage>}></HeaderBarButton>}, 
  {key: '2', item: <HeaderBarButton image={<HeaderBarButtonInfoImage></HeaderBarButtonInfoImage>}></HeaderBarButton>} 
]
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHmqA.jpg)

What is the right way to show an array of components on a navigation bar ?

Answer (score 2):

```
static navigationOptions = {
   title: "Categories",        
   headerRight: <View style={{flexDirection: 'row}}>
                   <HeaderBarButton image={<HeaderBarButtonSearchImage/>} />
                   <HeaderBarButton image={<HeaderBarButtonInfoImage/>} />
                <View/>,        
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the required data and inject the data into the component using the `map function.`

**Example**

```js
const button = [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: 'one'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'two'
      }
      ]
...
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      ...
      headerRight: button.map(
      (info,i) => { return(<Button
          key={i}
          onPress={navigation.getParam('increaseCount')}
          title={info.title}
          color={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#fff' : null}
        />)
      }),
    };
  };
```

Comment: @user1539434 If the error has been corrected, would you please select an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
 options={{
            title:"Title",
            headerTintColor: 'gold',
            headerTitleStyle: {
             textAlign:"center",
             flex:1 
            }
            headerLeft: () => (
             <View style={{marginHorizontal: 50, flexDirection: "row"}}>
              <Button
                onPress={() => console.log('This is a Left button!')}
                title="Menu"
              />
             </View>
            ),
            headerRight: () => (
             <View style={{marginHorizontal: 50, flexDirection: "row"}}>
              <Button
                onPress={() => console.log('This is a Right button!')}
                title="Info"
              />
              <Button
                onPress={() => console.log('This is a Right most button!')}
                title="Delete"
              />
             </View>
           )  
          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a "key".
Try this

```
static navigationOptions = {
   title: "Categories",        
   headerRight: [<HeaderBarButton key='btn01' image={<HeaderBarButtonSearchImage/>} />, <HeaderBarButton key='btn02' image={<HeaderBarButtonInfoImage/>} />],        
};
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply